# why spring-batch reader and writer use different transactions

Tags: spring-batch

[chunk oriented tasklet flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yX59.png)

I'm using spring-batch and composing 'ChunkOrientedTasklet'.

I saw the image above and realized that the reader and writer operate as a single transaction.

But it wasn't.

Why spring-batch reader and writer use different transactions?

So, reader and writer use different persistence context.

As a result, the select query occurs twice.
1 time for each page unit in the reader, 1 time for each merge in the writer
(Because the transaction is different, the entity is not fetched from the persistence context, and a new entity is fetched by querying the DB)

Select queries continue to occur in Writer in inserts, updates, and unchanged situations

reader - QuerydslPagingItemReader  (wrapped with JpaPagingItemReader)
writer - CustomItemWriter (wrapped with JpaItemWriter)

[Result]

[result-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUxTt.png)

[result-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwi2z.png)

[result-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqVjC.png)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `JpaPagingItemReader` uses a separate transaction so that items can be cached. Here is an excerpt from its [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html):

```
All entity access is performed within a new transaction, independent of any
existing Spring managed transactions.
```

This can be disabled using the [transacted](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html#setTransacted-boolean-) flag.

You can find more details and context here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1610